# How to Get the Selected Index of RadioButtonGroup in Adobe Flex 4+?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I know that it is possible to get the selected value on the change handler or item click handler of a radioGroupButton. Like this:

```
protected function rb1_itemClickHandler(event:ItemClickEvent):void
{
    var selectedValue:String=event.currentTarget.selectedValue.toString();          
}
```

But what I need is the index of the selected value. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `event.index` like in this example:

```
protected function rb1_itemClickHandler(event:ItemClickEvent):void
{
    trace(event.index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that't it: event.index.